# Storyboard in IOS 5 SDK but also target IOS 4 /3?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I love the idea of using storyboards, but unfortunately when I try to test this using IOS 4,
I change the deployment target to IOS 4 and I can't compile this anymore.
it said that `Storyboards is not supported for IOS 4.3 or later`.

So is it useful to use storyboards?
How can I write iPhone apps using storyboards so that they can be compatible with IOS 4?

Comment: What will your apps use in iOS 4 if not storyboards?

Comment: Also, I just answered a related question here: [Is the use of storyboards in Xcode 4.2 production ready and recommended? (c.f. previous XIB methods)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899650/is-the-use-of-storyboards-in-xcode-4-2-production-ready-and-recommended-c-f-p)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there's a reasonable way of doing it.

You *could* instantiate your Storyboards programatically (I think) but then you'd need something to fall back on on pre-iOS5 devices. And what would that be? Probably XIBs... which also continue to work on iOS5. You'd end up implementing everything twice. So, as I say, it may be possible but it's probably not practical.

Comment: But how about the roadmap for the future ?
if we already use the some IOS 5 feature, does it mean it will be easier for the future upgrade of IOS 6 ? may have something which need to have storyboard ?

Comment: We don't know about the roadmap. Apple don't preannounce. Using "modern" constructs in a new program will probably help in the future but there are no guarantees.