# The storyboard is automatically copied to the new project

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard

I have a project in Xcode, lets name it `A`, in which I have a story board and several views. I only need part of project `A`. Hence, I made a new project, `B`, and made a new `UIViewController`, with xib, and copied the two `UIViews` from project `A` to B. 
It looks like this now, where `RPM Display` and `Speed Display` are copied (by dragging from xib) from A to B.

[image]

`AnalogDisplayContainer` belongs to the class `PD_AnalogDisplayContainer`, and we have two outlets in class `PD_AnalogDisplayContainer`:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet PD_AnalogDisplay* speedDisplay;
@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet PD_AnalogDisplay* rpmDisplay;
```

which are connected to the respective views in `xib`. (We have exactly the same code in project `A`.) These `UIViews` have some `UILabels` as well, which are automatically copied in project `B`, and I need them as well. You see them here:

[image]

Up to here, the description of what I did. Now, the problem:
I have three outlets in class `PD_AnalogDisplay`.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel* unitLabel;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel* digitalIntegerValue;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel* digitalFloatValue;
```

However, so strangely, when I click on the small point beside these outlets, it shows me the connections to story board,

[image]

and when I click on the connection, I see the whole storyboard and views from project A.

[image]

In addition, these connections are not shown when I click on xib.

[image]

I searched in project B, there is no storyboard, or all these things I see in the previous picture, in form of code. So I don't know where it all come from. And I get the run time error:
**loaded the "RPMViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it brings previous reference wherever you copy it.
It is happening because the class name is same in project A and B.
**Create class name in project B other than class name in project A or slightly change variable name.**

Assign that class to your xib file.
You must recreate the `IBOutletes` from xib file.
Just copy the interface components not the code in .h file.

**Observations:**

- When I move project A to another location makes trick, reference destroyes.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. 1) I tried to copy the piece of code containing the outlets from project A to notepad and then to project B, but the connections are still there. 2) assign which class to xib? 3) Why do I see all the story board? I could it be copied?

Comment: I only see these connections when I click on the little point in the code itself (as shown in the picture). When I go to xib I don't see these connections (see the photo I just added), so I cannot delete them.

Comment: its because vieController class name..try diff name...I don't have valid reason of this...will update you whenever I know it

Comment: or slitely change variable name

Comment: Changed the location, and the name of the class. The story board is still there.