# How to install app created using storyboard in <iOS 5?

Tags: ipad, ios4

i'm new to iPhone i create an app using storyboard and tried to install in iOS 4 iPhone. my application is not installed in iPhone(iOS 4). i know storyboard installed in iOS 5. is there any possibilities to install it in < ios5. Thanks in advance.waiting for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't run apps designed using storyboards in older versions of iOS. A perfect explaination is given by Stephen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899990/storyboard-in-ios-5-sdk-but-also-target-ios-4-3) thread.